# Join two columns in one table to a column in another reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as below sql server:

Table1

```
ID  Result ProductId1 ProductId2
10  Pass   1          2
22  Failed 3          4
```

Table2

```
Id Name
1  ABC
2  DEF
3  GHI
4  JKL
```

How do I join Tables to get this result table:

Result

```
ID Result Name1 Name2
10 Pass   ABC   DEF
20 Failed GHI   JKL
```

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Can an ID be associated with only 2 products or might there be 3+ ?

Comment: Just two columns Product1 and Product2

Comment: are productid1 and productid2 always filled in? might productid2 ever be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to join to the reference table twice:

```
select t1.id, t2.result, t21.name as name1, t21.name as name2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t21
     on t1.productid1 = t21.id join
     table2 t22
     on t1.productid2 = t22.id;
```

Note the use of the table aliases in the `from` clause to distinguish between the two tables.